# reshaping a dataframe for prediction

Tags: r, reshape, reshape2

I just picked up on the package `reshape` today and I'm having some trouble to understand how it works.

I have the following dataframe:

```
name  workoutnum  time  weight   raceid     final position
tommy      1       12     140       1             2
tommy      2       14     140       1             2 
tommy      3       11     140       1             2
sarah      1       10     115       1             1
sarah      2       10     115       1             1
sarah      3       11     115       1             1
sarah      4       15     115       1             1
```

How would I put all this in one row? So the dataframe would look like:

```
    name  workoutnum1 workoutnum2 workoutnum3 workoutnum4 time1 time2 time3 time4 weight raceid final_position
   tommy     1            1           1           0        12     14   11    NA     140     1           2  
   sarah     1            1           1           1        10     10   11    15     115     1           1
```

So all columns would be attached to the workout values.

Is this even the proper way to do it?

Comment: i dont understand why you want workoutnum like that, this is close `reshape(dd, dir = 'wide', idvar = c('name','weight','final.position', 'raceid'), timevar = 'workoutnum', v.names = 'time', sep = '')`

Comment: Hi @rawr - perhaps I am thinking about this in the wrong way so I also welcome suggestions for a better dataframe that would have all data from the original one but still show positions in a single row for each person in each race. I will try your solution shortly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`reshape` seems like a natural part of what you want to do, but won't get you all the way there.

Here's a `reshape2` approach that fully melts the data, then casts it back to data.frame, with some tweaks along the way to get the desired output.

Note that in the call to `melt()`, the variables in the `id.vars` arguments will remain wide. Then in `dcast()`, the variable that'll be cast wide is on the RHS of the `~`.

```
library(reshape2)
library(dplyr)

# fully melt the data
d_melt <- melt(d, id.vars = c("name", "raceid", "position", "weight"))
# index the variables within name and variable
d_melt <- d_melt %>%
  group_by(name, variable) %>%
  mutate(i = row_number(),
         wide_variable = paste0(variable, i))

# cast as wide
d_wide <- dcast(d_melt, name + raceid + position + weight ~ wide_variable, value.var = "value")
# replace the workoutnum indices with indicators for missingness 
d_wide %>% mutate_each(funs(ifelse(!is.na(.), 1L, 0L)), matches("workoutnum\\d"))
#    name raceid position weight time1 time2 time3 time4 workoutnum1 workoutnum2
# 1 sarah      1        1    115    10    10    11    15           1           1
# 2 tommy      1        2    140    12    14    11    NA           1           1
#   workoutnum3 workoutnum4
# 1           1           1
# 2           1           0
```

Data:

```
structure(list(name = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("sarah", "tommy"), class = "factor"), workoutnum = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L), time = c(12L, 14L, 11L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 15L), weight = c(140L, 140L, 140L, 115L, 115L, 115L, 115L), raceid = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), position = c(2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L)), .Names = c("name", "workoutnum", "time", "weight", "raceid", "position"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -7L))
```

Comment: hi @effel, I can't try this now but i read over the code and it makes a lot of sense. I'll try this tomorrow and will let you know the results

Comment: hi @effel - this seems to have worked but when I make the prediction I get the following error `Error in object$levels[apply(L, 2, which.max)] : invalid subscript type 'list'` This wasn't happening before. Do you know what may be causing the error?

Comment: I see. If the data is in the format you need but you're getting an error at a later step in your analysis, I'd suggest posting a new question with a reproducible example of that problem.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an approach using `dcast` from "data.table", which reshapes a little more like the `reshape` function in base R.

The only change I've made to the data is the inclusion of another "time" variable though, as pointed out by @rawr in the comments, it almost seems like your "workoutnum" *is* the time variable.

I've used `getanID` from my "splitstackshape" package to generate the "time" variable, but you can create this variable in many different ways.

```
library(splitstackshape)
dcast(getanID(mydf, c("name", "raceid", "final_position")), 
      name + raceid + final_position ~ .id, 
      value.var = c("workoutnum", "time", "weight"))

##     name raceid final_position workoutnum_1 workoutnum_2 workoutnum_3
## 1: sarah      1              1            1            2            3
## 2: tommy      1              2            1            2            3
##    workoutnum_4 time_1 time_2 time_3 time_4 weight_1 weight_2 weight_3 weight_4
## 1:            4     10     10     11     15      115      115      115      115
## 2:           NA     12     14     11     NA      140      140      140       NA
```

If you're using `getanID`, you can also use `reshape` like this:

```
reshape(getanID(mydf, c("name", "raceid", "final_position")), 
        idvar = c("name", "raceid", "final_position"), timevar = ".id", 
        direction = "wide")
##     name raceid final_position workoutnum.1 time.1 weight.1 workoutnum.2 time.2
## 1: tommy      1              2            1     12      140            2     14
## 2: sarah      1              1            1     10      115            2     10
##    weight.2 workoutnum.3 time.3 weight.3 workoutnum.4 time.4 weight.4
## 1:      140            3     11      140           NA     NA       NA
## 2:      115            3     11      115            4     15      115
```

but `dcast` would be more efficient in general.